# Trying to save different model before creation?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rolify

I am trying to add a user role according to Rolify gem in my devise User model.

What I basically want to achieve is that, if the user has selected that he is a student or a teacher in the registration page itself, after the creation of the user, it should add the required roles to the user.

Please note that I am not storing the 'role' in the User table. I am just using attr_accessor to send me an initial value to compare.

This is my User model code :

```
# == Schema Information
#
# Table name: users
#
#  id                     :integer          not null, primary key
#  email                  :string(255)      default(""), not null
#  encrypted_password     :string(255)      default(""), not null
#  reset_password_token   :string(255)
#  reset_password_sent_at :datetime
#  remember_created_at    :datetime
#  sign_in_count          :integer          default(0), not null
#  current_sign_in_at     :datetime
#  last_sign_in_at        :datetime
#  current_sign_in_ip     :string(255)
#  last_sign_in_ip        :string(255)
#  created_at             :datetime         not null
#  updated_at             :datetime         not null
#  avatar                 :string(255)
#  username               :string(255)
#

class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # This is for the user roles.
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  attr_accessor :role
  # Adding the carrierwave uploader
  mount_uploader :avatar, AvatarUploader


  before_create :add_specified_role

  def add_specified_role
    if self.role == 0
      # I am sure I am messing it up here and this is not the way.. :/
      after_create :add_student_role
    elsif self.role == 1
      after_create :add_teacher_role
    end
  end


  def add_student_role
    self.add_role(:student) if self.roles.blank?
  end


  def add_teacher_role
    self.add_role(:teacher) if self.roles.blank?
  end


end
```

However, it does not seem to be working as when I check the roles, the role has not been added and I am sure I am doing something wrong.

What is the correct way to achieve the above task?

Answer (score 0):

callback should be

`after_create :add_specified_role , if: proc { |a| a.roles.blank? }`

instead of

`before_create :add_specified_role`

And method should

```
  def add_specified_role
   if role == 0
    add_role(:student)
   elsif role == 1
    add_role(:teacher)
   end
  end
```

Comment: I am not storing the 'role' in the User table. So it is not present for a after_create callback as there is no column with 'role' present hence after_create in this current scenario will not work. I don't want to store another role column in the user table as it would render the whole purpose of the Rolify gem useless..

Comment: @SankalpSingha Storing another role in user table means??? , Rolfiy does for you, you have added ` attr_accessor :role` which is not a field of table

Comment: @SankalpSingha rolify store the roles in another roles table which is has_and belongs to many association with user